# mp4 video won't load in Safari (Status: pending / Type: undefined)

Tags: html, video, safari, mp4, ogg

```
<source src="../../_media/videos/Video.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
```

I am wondering why this video is not loading in Safari 5 - Chrome / Firefox are working perfectly.

WebSniffer is telling me the correct type but in the safari dev tools i receive Type=undefined.

Does anyone have a clue? I also added a .htaccess but am not sure where exactly to place it - root, media folder or html folder?

Great if anyone could help me

Comment: Try checking HTTP headers of your video file GET request

Comment: i did - using WebSniffer - Type = mp4/video so no big deal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the issue last night. Since I was on a testing environment using https and authorization Safari could not load the videos.

All other browsers did have no problem with it - Safari however does have issues with this:)

Comment: Here are some additional infos on the apple-forums: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2627413?start=0&tstart=0 and https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3026341 for iOS.